# Magento featured products include tax

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

On my homepage for my shop I currently have a featured products area.  The problem is it shows the price including the tax rate where throughout the site I've got it set up to display without the tax & then for the the tax to be added on within the cart.

I'm using the following code for my featured products pricing.

```
<p class="price">&pound;<?php echo Mage::helper('tax')->getPrice($_product, $_product->getFinalPrice(), 2);?>(+VAT)</p>
```

is there a simple way to force the outcome excluding tax as it seems to be ignoring my general settings?

It also seems to ignore the general rule for decimal places too.  If I need to post the full code please just say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third parameter of Mage::helper('tax')->getPrice() function indicates if price have to be shown with or without tax. So either set it to `null` or just drop it.

For the rounding issue please try Mage::helper('core')->currency() instead of Mage::helper('tax')->getPrice(). So your final code should look like this:

```
echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($_product->getFinalPrice());
```

Comment: brilliant thankyou changing the code to   
    <?php echo Mage::helper('tax')->getPrice($_product, $_product->getFinalPrice(), null);?>
sorted the problem with the tax

Comment: it still however rounds up to the nearest decimal so say £100.00 would just be £100 how can i force this through to stay at £100.00 ive noticed this seemw to be the case on the category pages but not the product ones